# Obtaining user uids in a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is a the JSON of my databse node :

```
{
  "1YrpX2W2xnMPoy4YGpZcOE0xJ5g2" : {
    "email" : "muyi@hotmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Muyiz",
    "selection" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
    "teamname" : "awon",
    "total" : 12,
    "userName" : "motmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 12,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  },
  "6K9rQiZQ3jaV38WWtDbNwxhqIwc2" : {
    "email" : "domi@gmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Dai",
    "selection" : 0,
    "teamname" : "Bayern Neverlosin'",
    "total" : 0,
    "userName" : "dai@gmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 0,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  },
  "9OgN4HyMtARaQEQV1mKQ5lyE1992" : {
    "email" : "jonail.com",
    "fullname" : "Jon",
    "selection" : [ 40, 8, 10, 24, 18, 34 ],
    "teamname" : "Chad fc",
    "total" : 0,
    "userName" : "jojin@gmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 8,
    "week6" : 0,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  },
  "AGVZAUye5ZbZgvwCOpMeDkoOsEU2" : {
    "email" : "ihe@gmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Emeka Iheme",
    "selection" : 0,
    "teamname" : "Young Money",
    "total" : 0,
    "userName" : "ihem@gmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 0,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  }
}
```

Is there a way to access the the user uid for each user under the user node?

The goals is to have the following code run in my cloud function:

```
ref = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/week1`);
```

But as it stands, the following cloud function returns an error that user is not defined:

```
exports.update = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}')
    .onWrite(event=>{
ref = admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/week1`);
return ref.set(50);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define a wildcard in a database trigger:

```
functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}')
```

That `uid` wildcard is accessible from the passed event as `event.params.uid`.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for more information.

Comment: thanks. But the result of this was the creation of a node in my firebase database with the key {uid} and value 50 as oppossed to setting the value 50 to each user.